# Return two most recent costs for all products from a table of product costs

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to return the last two costs for every product from two tables for a given time period using Snowflake's SQL.

Here are the sample tables

```
**VendorItemCosts**
| ID | VENDORITEMID | COSTCENTS | UPDATEDAT                     |
|----|--------------|-----------|-------------------------------|
| 1  | 442720       | 1209      | 2022-03-11 20:54:16.666 +0000 |
| 2  | 442720       | 1399      | 2022-03-12 20:23:15.342 +0000 |
| 3  | 2878218      | 3432      | 2022-03-12 20:54:32.642 +0000 |
| 4  | 2878218      | 3567      | 2022-03-13 20:55:11.123 +0000 |

**VendorItems**
| ID | VENDORITEM | SKU  | NAME    |
|----|------------|------|---------|
| 1  | 442720     | 1234 | T-Shirt |
| 2  | 2878218    | 5678 | Shorts  |
```

Here is my attempt that returns it for a specific VENDORITEM but I need it to return ALL of them at once.

```
    select VI1.ID as "VendorItem ID",
       VI1.Name as "VendorItem Name",
       LATEST.ID as "Latest ID",
       LATEST.COSTCENTS as "Latest CostCents",
       LATEST.UPDATEDAT as "Latest UpdatedAt",
       LATEST2.ID as "Latest2 ID",
       LATEST2.COSTCENTS as "Latest2 CostCents", 
       LATEST2.UPDATEDAT  as "Latest2 UpdatedAt"
    from VENDORITEMS as VI1
    join (select top 1 * from VENDORITEMCOSTS as VIC1 where VIC1.VENDORITEMID = 442720 
          order by VIC1.ID desc) as LATEST on VI1.ID = LATEST.VENDORITEMID  --Returns most recent VendorItemCosts record
    join (select top 1 * from VENDORITEMCOSTS as VIC1 where VIC1.ID < (     --Returns 2nd most recent VendorItemCosts record
        select MAX(VIC2.ID) from VENDORITEMCOSTS as VIC2 where VIC2.VENDORITEMID = 442720)
        and VIC1.VENDORITEMID = 442720 order by VIC1.ID desc) as LATEST2 on VI1.ID = LATEST2.VENDORITEMID
    where VI1.ID = 442720 and
    LATEST.UPDATEDAT > '2022-03-01' and
    LATEST.UPDATEDAT < '2022-03-25'
```

Here is the result of the above query

```
| VendorItem ID | VendorItem Name | Latest ID | Latest CostCents | Latest UpdatedAt              | Latest2 ID | Latest2 CostCents | Latest2 UpdatedAt             |
|---------------|-----------------|-----------|------------------|-------------------------------|------------|-------------------|-------------------------------|
| 442720        | T-Shirt         | 2         | 1399             | 2022-03-12 20:23:15.342 +0000 | 1          | 1209              | 2022-03-11 20:54:16.666 +0000 |
```

This is the result I am looking for

```
| VendorItem ID | VendorItem Name | Latest ID | Latest CostCents | Latest UpdatedAt              | Latest2 ID | Latest2 CostCents | Latest2 UpdatedAt             |
|---------------|-----------------|-----------|------------------|-------------------------------|------------|-------------------|-------------------------------|
| 442720        | T-Shirt         | 2         | 1399             | 2022-03-12 20:23:15.342 +0000 | 1          | 1209              | 2022-03-11 20:54:16.666 +0000 |
| 2878218       | Shorts          | 4         | 3567             | 2022-03-13 20:55:11.123 +0000 | 3          | 3432              | 2022-03-12 20:54:32.642 +0000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Step - 1:

Given date range = From '2022-03-01' to '2022-03-25'.

First we need to find latest items in this date range.

Latest Items means the item for which the ID in VendorItemCosts table is MAX.

[Above is based on query, given in question which is doing MAX(VIC2.ID) OR order by VIC1.ID desc]

```
with vendor_cte(ID,VENDORITEMID,COSTCENTS,UPDATEDAT) as
(select * from values
(1,442720,1273,'2021-03-10 20:51:16.666'::timestamp),
(2,442720,1209,'2021-03-11 20:54:16.666'::timestamp),
(3,442720,1399,'2022-03-18 20:28:15.342'::timestamp),
(4,442720,1476,'2022-03-27 20:52:16.666'::timestamp),
(5,2878218,1256,'2022-03-12 20:54:16.666'::timestamp),
(6,2878218,3432,'2021-03-18 20:55:32.642'::timestamp),
(7,2878218,3667,'2022-03-16 20:53:11.123'::timestamp),
(8,2878218,3597,'2022-03-28 20:51:11.123'::timestamp),
(9,3878218,3597,'2021-03-28 20:51:11.123'::timestamp),
(10,3878218,3597,'2022-03-18 20:51:11.123'::timestamp),
(11,3878218,3597,'2022-03-28 20:51:11.123'::timestamp)
), item_cte (id, vendoritem, sku, name) as
(
select * from values
(1,442720,1234,'T-Shirt'),
(2,2878218,4678,'Jeans'),
(3,3878218,5078,'Jackets')
), latest_cte (latest_id, VENDORITEMID,latest_costcents,latest_updatedat, name) as
(
select
vc.id latest_id,
vc.VENDORITEMID,
vc.COSTCENTS latest_costcents,
vc.UPDATEDAT latest_updatedat,
ic.name
from vendor_cte vc, item_cte ic
where vc.VENDORITEMID = ic.vendoritem
and vc.UPDATEDAT between
'2022-03-01'::timestamp and '2022-03-25'::timestamp -- Filter Date range first
qualify row_number()
over (partition by vc.VENDORITEMID order by vc.id desc)<2 -- Then, select the latest item
)
select * from latest_cte;
```

| LATEST_ID | VENDORITEMID | LATEST_COSTCENTS | LATEST_UPDATEDAT | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 442720 | 1399 | 2022-03-18 20:28:15.342 | T-Shirt |
| 7 | 2878218 | 3667 | 2022-03-16 20:53:11.123 | Jeans |
| 10 | 3878218 | 3597 | 2022-03-18 20:51:11.123 | Jackets |

Step - 2: **Main step**

Next what is needed is to get the previous item price.
That is the item, previous to the one selected in step - 1.

Using the data-set built so far from the step - 1, putting that in a CTE -

```
with vendor_cte(ID,VENDORITEMID,COSTCENTS,UPDATEDAT) as
(select * from values
(1,442720,1273,'2021-03-10 20:51:16.666'::timestamp),
(2,442720,1209,'2021-03-11 20:54:16.666'::timestamp),
(3,442720,1399,'2022-03-18 20:28:15.342'::timestamp),
(4,442720,1476,'2022-03-27 20:52:16.666'::timestamp),
(5,2878218,1256,'2022-03-12 20:54:16.666'::timestamp),
(6,2878218,3432,'2021-03-18 20:55:32.642'::timestamp),
(7,2878218,3667,'2022-03-16 20:53:11.123'::timestamp),
(8,2878218,3597,'2022-03-28 20:51:11.123'::timestamp),
(9,3878218,3597,'2021-03-28 20:51:11.123'::timestamp),
(10,3878218,3597,'2022-03-18 20:51:11.123'::timestamp),
(11,3878218,3597,'2022-03-28 20:51:11.123'::timestamp)
), item_cte (id, vendoritem, sku, name) as
(
select * from values
(1,442720,1234,'T-Shirt'),
(2,2878218,4678,'Jeans'),
(3,3878218,5078,'Jackets')
), latest_cte (latest_id, VENDORITEMID,latest_costcents,latest_updatedat, name) as
(
select
vc.id latest_id,
vc.VENDORITEMID,
vc.COSTCENTS latest_costcents,
vc.UPDATEDAT latest_updatedat,
ic.name
from vendor_cte vc, item_cte ic
where vc.VENDORITEMID = ic.vendoritem
and vc.UPDATEDAT between
'2022-03-01'::timestamp and '2022-03-25'::timestamp -- Filter Date range first
qualify row_number()
over (partition by vc.VENDORITEMID order by vc.id desc)<2 -- Then, select the latest item
)
select lt.*,
vc.id prev_ID,
vc.costcents prev_costcents,
vc.UPDATEDAT prev_UPDATEDAT
from vendor_cte vc right join latest_cte lt
on lt.VENDORITEMID = vc.VENDORITEMID
and lt.latest_id > vc.id
qualify row_number() -- This qualify will select the latest previous item
over (partition by latest_id order by prev_id desc)<2; -- order by prev_id to get only last prev_id
```

| LATEST_ID | VENDORITEMID | LATEST_COSTCENTS | LATEST_UPDATEDAT | NAME | PREV_ID | PREV_COSTCENTS | PREV_UPDATEDAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 442720 | 1399 | 2022-03-18 20:28:15.342 | T-Shirt | 2 | 1209 | 2021-03-11 20:54:16.666 |
| 7 | 2878218 | 3667 | 2022-03-16 20:53:11.123 | Jeans | 6 | 3432 | 2021-03-18 20:55:32.642 |
| 10 | 3878218 | 3597 | 2022-03-18 20:51:11.123 | Jackets | 9 | 3597 | 2021-03-28 20:51:11.123 |

The two CTE in last query can be combined into one as -

```
select
vc.id latest_id,
vc.VENDORITEMID,
vc.COSTCENTS latest_costcents,
vc.UPDATEDAT latest_updatedat,
ic.name,
vcp.id prev_ID,
vcp.COSTCENTS prev_COSTCENTS,
vcp.UPDATEDAT prev_UPDATEDAT
from vendor_cte vc, item_cte ic, vendor_cte vcp
where vc.VENDORITEMID = vcp.VENDORITEMID
and vc.VENDORITEMID = ic.vendoritem
and vcp.id < vc.id
and vc.UPDATEDAT between
'2022-03-01'::timestamp and '2022-03-25'::timestamp 
qualify row_number()
over (partition by vc.VENDORITEMID order by vc.id,vcp.id desc)<2
```

Comment: Thx @Pankaj, but I'm looking for the result to be a row for each VendorItem and the CostCents for two most recent records in the VendorItemCosts table as I show above in the "This is the result I am looking for" code block.

Comment: You can adjust the qualify clause to get last for each VendorItem. I'll include same in answer too.

Comment: Pankaj, what I'm looking for is each VendorItem row to have BOTH the latest CostCents & UpdatedAt AND the previous CostCents & UpdatedAt.  From this I can then compute the absolute change in cost and the %.

Comment: I missed scrolling to right in your sample expected output. Now I have edited back the answer. In that I used, 3 rows per item to show the distinction of choosing the latest two

Comment: One last update, I need the date filter to only apply to the lastest  change in price.  RIght now, it's filtering out all the prices changes to that date range and then comparing them.  I want the most recent price change in the date range and then show previous price.

If you change the first 2 rows in your table to be 2021 and then rerun it, I want to get 2 results comparing the latest price to the ones in the past which should include the 2021 date.

Comment: Edited my response as per the latest comment. I have used ID to get max as per query in question, though we can also use date (UPDATEDAT) too for the same.